# Adding a Group as a member of a Group using Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure Graph API with Azure AD B2C and I'm trying to add a Group as a member of a Group

I have successfully preformed a range of other calls against Azure Graph API including adding a User as a Member of a Group.

This is the call I'm making
URL:

`POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/groups/{groupId}/$links/members?api-version=1.6`

Body:

```
{
    "url": "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/directoryObjects/{groupToAdd}"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "An invalid operation was included in the following modified references: 'members'."
        },
        "requestId": "2545d9bf-68c9-44bf-a9ba-1a2976e0c055",
        "date": "2019-09-11T03:11:37"
    }
}
```

The exact same call worked when using a User's ObjectId but using a Groups throws the error.

Maybe related, the "Group Memberships" is missing in Azure when viewing a Group
[image: MissingGroupMemberships]

Update:
When I first posted this question I was missing an important piece of information. This is Graph API calls against Azure Active Directory B2C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have nested Groups within Azure Active Directory B2C Instances

See: [AAD B2C Limitations and restrictions](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations.md)

> Nested group memberships aren't supported in Azure AD B2C tenants. There are no plans to add this capability.

Answer (score 0):

> the "Group Memberships" is missing in Azure when viewing a Group

In my site, the group Memberships still in Azure AD Group tab, I use the following code and it add Group as a member of a Group successfully.

```
https://graph.windows.net/tenantId/groups/securityGroupObjectId/$links/members  
{
    "url": "https://graph.windows.net/tenantId/groups/securityGroupObjectIdToAdd"
}
```

[image]

Note: Make sure `securityGroupObjectIdToAdd` is the correct objectId. Should be the objectId that is returned by `az ad group list`, which is different to the object ID that in the portal! Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7621).